# Error in sending mail using outlook rest api in python

Tags: python, django, outlook-restapi

I am using the following code to send an email using outlook rest api in python.

outlookservice.py

```
import requests
import uuid
import json

outlook_api_endpoint = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0{0}'

# Generic API Sending
def make_api_call(method, url, token, user_email, payload = None, parameters = None):
  # Send these headers with all API calls
  headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'python_tutorial/1.0',
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
              'Accept' : 'application/json',
              'X-AnchorMailbox' : user_email }

  # Use these headers to instrument calls. Makes it easier
  # to correlate requests and responses in case of problems
  # and is a recommended best practice.
  request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
  instrumentation = { 'client-request-id' : request_id,
                      'return-client-request-id' : 'true' }

  headers.update(instrumentation)

  response = None

  if (method.upper() == 'GET'):
      response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = parameters)
  elif (method.upper() == 'DELETE'):
      response = requests.delete(url, headers = headers, params = parameters)
  elif (method.upper() == 'PATCH'):
      headers.update({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' })
      response = requests.patch(url, headers = headers, data = json.dumps(payload), params = parameters)
  elif (method.upper() == 'POST'):
      headers.update({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' })
      response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = json.dumps(payload), params = parameters)

  return response


def get_me(access_token):
  get_me_url = outlook_api_endpoint.format('/Me')

  # Use OData query parameters to control the results
  #  - Only return the DisplayName and EmailAddress fields
  query_parameters = {'$select': 'DisplayName,EmailAddress'}

  r = make_api_call('GET', get_me_url, access_token, "", parameters = query_parameters)

  if (r.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
    return r.json()
  else:
    return "{0}: {1}".format(r.status_code, r.text)

def get_my_messages(access_token, user_email):
  get_messages_url = outlook_api_endpoint.format('/Me/MailFolders/Inbox/Messages')

  query_parameters = {'$top': '10',
                      '$select': 'ReceivedDateTime,Subject,From',
                      '$orderby': 'ReceivedDateTime DESC'}

  r = make_api_call('GET', get_messages_url, access_token, user_email, parameters = query_parameters)

  if (r.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
    return r.json()
  else:
    return "{0}: {1}".format(r.status_code, r.text)


def send_message(access_token,user_email):
     get_messages_url = outlook_api_endpoint.format('/Me/sendmail')
     query_parameters = {
  "Message": {
    "Subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "Text",
      "Content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "ToRecipients": [
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "garthf@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "Name": "menu.txt",
        "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
      }
    ]
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": "false"
  }

     r = make_api_call('POST', get_messages_url, access_token, user_email, parameters = query_parameters)
     if (r.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
        print r.json()
        return r.json()
     else:
        return "{0}: {1}".format(r.status_code, r.text)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from tutorial.authhelper import get_signin_url,get_token_from_code, get_token_from_refresh_token, get_access_token
import requests
import time
from tutorial.outlookservice import get_me,get_my_messages,send_message

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
  redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8000/tutorial/gettoken/"
  sign_in_url = get_signin_url(redirect_uri)
  return HttpResponse('<a href="' + sign_in_url +'">Click here to sign in and view your mail</a>')

def gettoken(request):
  auth_code = request.GET['code']
  redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8000/tutorial/gettoken/"
  token = get_token_from_code(auth_code, redirect_uri)
  access_token = token['access_token']
  user = get_me(access_token)
  refresh_token = token['refresh_token']
  expires_in = token['expires_in']

  expiration = int(time.time()) + expires_in - 300

  # Save the token in the session
  request.session['access_token'] = access_token
  request.session['refresh_token'] = refresh_token
  request.session['token_expires'] = expiration
  request.session['user_email'] = user['EmailAddress']
  return HttpResponse('User Email: {0}, Access token:   {1}'.format(user['EmailAddress'], access_token))
```

This is the function where send_message is called

```
def mail(request):

  access_token = get_access_token(request,request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('tutorial:gettoken')))
  user_email = request.session['user_email']

  if not access_token:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tutorial:home'))
  else:
    abc = send_message(access_token,user_email)
    return HttpResponse(abc)
```

I am getting the following error while compiling it in Django

> 400: {"error":{"code":"RequestBroker-ParseUri","message":"Query option 'Message' was specified more than once, but it must be specified at most once."}}

Comment: Can you please share the request body and request uri? As seen on the wire

Answer (score 0):

I know this is somewhat old, but did you try removing the "Message" field from the `query_parameters` JSON in the `send_message` method?
Try creating your JSON as if the Message field already exists and you only need to provide/fill the inner fields. Like this:

`query_parameters = {
    "Subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "Body": {
      "ContentType": "Text",
      "Content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "ToRecipients": [
      {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "garthf@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "Name": "menu.txt",
        "ContentBytes": "bWFjIGFuZCBjaGVlc2UgdG9kYXk="
      }
    ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

In your send_email function in outlookservice.py, you have sent the message content to make_api_call as parameters, instead of as payload. The following should correct your issue:

```
r = make_api_call('POST', get_messages_url, access_token, user_email, payload = query_parameters)
```